Next.js: Framer Motion bundle size not reducing despite optimization steps
I've been optimising my Next.js project using the Framer Motion animation library. According to the Framer Motion documentation, I've implemented steps to improve performance and reduce the JavaScript bundle size. However, despite these changes, the bundle size remains the same.
Here's what I've done so far:

Wrapped the children in Root Layout with a Client Component Provider:
I wrapped my root layout with a client component and wrapped all children with LazyMotion and passed the domAnimation prop to it, based on the Framer Motion documentation.

layout.tsx
<html lang={lang}>
      <body className={ltrFont.className}>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          <ProgressBarProvider>
            <LazyMotionProvider>
              <div id="mega-menu" className="fixed left-0 z-[100] w-full"></div>
              <div
                id="mobile-menu"
                className="fixed left-0 z-[110] w-full"
              ></div>
              <div id="view-proposal-mobile-menu" className="fixed z-20" />

              <ToastContainer />

              <OverlayScrollbar lang={lang}>{children}</OverlayScrollbar>
            </LazyMotionProvider>
          </ProgressBarProvider>
        </NextAuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>

LazyMotionProvider.tsx
"use client";

import { LazyMotion, domAnimation } from "framer-motion";
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

export interface LazyMotionProviderProps {}

const LazyMotionProvider: React.FC<
  PropsWithChildren<LazyMotionProviderProps>
> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
   <LazyMotion features={domAnimation}>
    {children}
    </LazyMotion>
  )
};

export default LazyMotionProvider;


I replaced all motion imports with m imports as explained in the documentation.

import { m } from 'framer-motion';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <m.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }}>
    Hello World
  </m.div>
);

export default MyComponent;

My VSCode extension calculates the size of m as 13.7kb (5.5kb zipped), whereas motion was 99kb (32.4kb zipped). Despite changing all imports, the overall bundle size did not change and remains the same as before.
Question:
Why is my bundle size not reducing after following the optimization steps for Framer Motion in my Next.js project? Is there something I'm missing or doing incorrectly? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Context:

Nextjs version: [14.0.2]
Framer Motion version: [^10.16.5]

